# Add extracted dataframe header to exsisting dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Dataframe 1:**

Crated empty dataframe

```
mat=pd.DataFrame(index=range(rows),columns=range(columns)) #Usually 1 row 4-5 columns
```

Extracted data Stored in cell (by for loop)

```
mat.iloc[0, mat.columns.get_loc(count)]=name_temp[1] 
   count=count+1

print(mat) 


       0        1      
0    First  Second
```

**Dataframe 2:**

Data frame in text file

```
A   B
0.0 0.0
9.999999960041974e-12   3.33111256499353e-09
1.0120053292895381e-11  3.371583784551049e-09
1.03601599586022e-11    3.453486421669065e-09
```

I read this using

```
data = pd.read_csv("stack.txt",sep='\t')
```

To add dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 I tried to add as dataframe 1 as header

```
data.columns=mat

data = pd.read_csv("stack.txt",sep='\t',names=mat)

mat.values.tolist()   #Assumed listing dataframe1 using data.columns
```

How can I add the dataframe 1 as header to dataframe 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your create `data` df by:

```
data = pd.read_csv("stack.txt",sep='\t')
```

Try this:

```
data.columns = mat.iloc[0].tolist()
```

**Explanation:**

The first line of `mat` is determined by `mat.iloc[0]`.

Now, you want to set this as header(or columns) of `data` df. So, assign it to `data.columns` . This accepts a list object, so convert mat's row to a list by `tolist()`.

Hence, the net command becomes:

```
data.columns = mat.iloc[0].tolist()
```

Comment: This helped me to achieve my objective. @Mayank Porwal since I am novice can you share description of that line of code?

Comment: @Pai Have updated my answer with explanation of commands. Please check.

Comment: this leaves me with length mismatch I will edit the query. Please check my another query related to this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415778/writes-index-in-text-file-after-column-drop-python

Comment: What if dataframe 2 is not labled with A and B (unlabled) with columns initially is there any alternative to combine dataframe 1 and 2

Comment: You still want to put first row of df1 as column header for df2, right? So, it does not matter if df2 has `A and B` labeled. It will still run fine. Please test it first.