# Writes index in text file after column drop python

Tags: python, file, dataframe, text-files

Objective is to remove first column and name the dataframe with header then write it into another text file or same one.

**Dataframe 1:**

```
0       0.05   0.4    0.6
1       0.3    0.5    0.2
2       0.4    0.7    0.9
```

I read the file using

```
data = pd.read_csv(test_data,sep='\t',index_col=False)
```

Column drop-

```
data.drop(data.columns[0], axis=1,inplace=True)
```

When I print this data

```
Unnamed:1       0.05   0.4    0.6
NaN     0.3    0.5    0.2
Nan     0.4    0.7    0.9
```

So to be more careful i used

```
data.dropna(how ='all') #how='any' also been used
```

No changes seen

Tried even this

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip() # So that it removes drop column spaces and allows me to name headers
```

Had to combine header which is dataframe 2 to dataframe 1 using this

```
data.columns = mat.iloc[0].tolist() # mat is dataframe with 1 row 3 columns
```

Next task was to write to text file.

```
data.to_csv(result_data, sep='\t',index=False)
```

I get length mismatch error Expected axis 2 elements, new values have 3 elements
But I have dropped column 0

Where A B C are from dataframe 2 which is processed earlier

Sample output required

```
   A      B      C
  0.05   0.4    0.6
  0.3    0.5    0.2
  0.4    0.7    0.9
```

Comment: Perhaps, a sample output?

Comment: @DityBit I have updated sample output

Comment: You mean that you want `data.to_csv(index=False, header=['A', 'B', 'C'])`?

Comment: No I have processed dataframe 2 which will have strings of eg: 1X3  A B C for which I used data.columns = mat.iloc[0].tolist() to add as header

Comment: If I follow : data = pd.read_csv(test_data,sep='\t',index_col=0) > data.drop(data.columns[0], axis=1,inplace=True,) > data.to_csv(result_data,  sep='\t',index=False) > data = pd.read_csv(result_data,sep='\t',index_col=0) > data.columns = mat.iloc[0].tolist() > data.to_csv(ascii_data, sep='\t',index=False) This will give me length mismatch while adding columns using "data.columns" which has same number of column header as in data